# Lebesgue–Stieltjes Integration in R

Tags: r, integration

I calculated a distribution function numerically. **First** I plot the function. It looks wrong around 0.05. Is this due to rounding errors, please? [image]

**Second**, I need to find the corresponding first and second non-central moments. That is,

EX = int x dF(x)

EX^2 = int x^2 dF(x)

Can I do this type of Lebesgue–Stieltjes integration in `R`, please? Is there a build-in method, please? If not in `R`, what package offers such calculation, please?

I guess alternatively, I can find the numerical differentiation f(x) of F(x) and then conduct the usually integration like

EX = int x f(x) dx

But I remember from somewhere that numerical differentiation is much less stable. Which is the right way, please?

FYI my functions are attached below.

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(matrixcalc) 

VAR <- matrix(c(1.043856e-03, 5.044899e-04, 3.239951e-04, 2.330992e-04, 0.0001779055, 0.0001403866, 0.0001127118, 9.074962e-05, 7.157144e-05,
                5.044899e-04, 5.485889e-04, 3.523165e-04, 2.534751e-04, 0.0001934568, 0.0001526582, 0.0001225642, 9.868232e-05, 7.782773e-05,
                3.239951e-04, 3.523165e-04, 3.878844e-04, 2.790645e-04, 0.0002129870, 0.0001680697, 0.0001349376, 1.086447e-04, 8.568475e-05,
                2.330992e-04, 2.534751e-04, 2.790645e-04, 3.123147e-04, 0.0002383642, 0.0001880950, 0.0001510153, 1.215896e-04, 9.589399e-05,
                1.779055e-04, 1.934568e-04, 2.129870e-04, 2.383642e-04, 0.0002728857, 0.0002153361, 0.0001728863, 1.391990e-04, 1.097820e-04,
                1.403866e-04, 1.526582e-04, 1.680697e-04, 1.880950e-04, 0.0002153361, 0.0002548851, 0.0002046389, 1.647645e-04, 1.299447e-04,
                1.127118e-04, 1.225642e-04, 1.349376e-04, 1.510153e-04, 0.0001728863, 0.0002046389, 0.0002555744, 2.057751e-04, 1.622886e-04,
                9.074962e-05, 9.868232e-05, 1.086447e-04, 1.215896e-04, 0.0001391990, 0.0001647645, 0.0002057751, 2.840218e-04, 2.239993e-04,
                7.157144e-05, 7.782773e-05, 8.568475e-05, 9.589399e-05, 0.0001097820, 0.0001299447, 0.0001622886, 2.239993e-04, 3.974881e-04),
              nrow=9, ncol=9, byrow=TRUE)

is.symmetric.matrix(VAR)
is.positive.definite(VAR)
kappa(VAR)

CDF <- function(x){
  summand <- rep(0, 5)

  for(j in 5:9){
    choice <- combn(9, j)
    for(i in 1:ncol(choice)){
      ub <- rep(Inf, 9)
      ub[choice[, i]] <- x
      summand[j-4] <- summand[j-4] + as.numeric(pmvnorm(lower=rep(-Inf, 9), upper=ub, sigma=VAR))
    }
  }

  l <- c(1, -5, 15, -35, 70)
  as.numeric(t(l)%*%summand)
}

CDF <- Vectorize(CDF)

x <- seq(-0.1, 0.1, by=0.01)
y <- CDF(x)

plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2)
```

Comment: I don't think the term "Lebesgue–Stieltjes" really applies to numerical methods of integration. There is an `integrate` function in R that would handle calculating non-pathologic integrals. It's not going to be able to handle correctly cases where f(x) = 1 when x is irrational, but fx=0 where x is rational.

Comment: @BondedDust I do not understand what you said. Given my CDF, is there a way to find its moments numerically, please?

Comment: Your CDF function is gawdawful slow so the integration using it is even slower. My computer has been slaving away at the calculation of `integrate(CDF, 10, 10)` for several minutes now and I will soon terminate the process ( or go out for dinner). I'm expecting the value to be near 10 if it ever completes. It did complete and I get `10 with absolute error < 0.00016`

Comment: It may be helpful for readers to give the formula that you're trying to integrate; could there be an exact method? (or at least a way of reducing the variance that comes with repeated calls to `pmvnorm`...)

Answer (score 2):

I initially plotted the result I got from taking  first differences from `numCDF <- CDF( seq(-10, 10, length=100) )`, but that was rather disappointing, since only one value was different than 0. So I restricted the focus to:

```
 numCDF <- CDF( seq(-.10, .10, length=100) )
 plot( diff(numCDF) )
```

[image]

Simply plotting the values of numCDF produces similar chaotic results in the region where you expressed concern.

[image]

So I think maybe your function is not sufficiently well-behaved to yield good results.